# Cloudfront doesn't forward cookie to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cookies, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a react application uploaded on S3 and node application on Lambda which has endpoints available for only authenticated users. Authentication on React app is done by `Cognito`, I have hardcoded Google Sign in button. After authentication, user is redirected to S3 endpoint(`/Code`) which gets the  `code=...` from URL, sends it using `Axios` to specific Lambda endpoint. From Lambda side when it receives `code` it gets token from `/oauth2/token` and sends it back to S3, which sets it as a cookie using `universal-cookie` package. After this S3 sends every request to Lambda using `{credentials: true}`

For Cognito authentication to work properly, it needs login Callback url to be HTTPS. I created a `Cloudfront` distribution to forward requests to S3. So I setup my callback url to be `Cloudfront` URL. The authentication is done correctly and I can see that cookie is set and is sent in every request:

[image]

But it's not forwarded to S3, I see a request that is sent to Lambda:

[image]

Which doesn't contain the cookie. I changed Cloudfront behaviour:

[image]

But it didn't help. I'm missing some knowledge in Cloudfront. Should I set some other option to forward Cookies to S3?

Comment: I am confused what S3 has to do with cookies, what should S3 do with them? How is the lambda involved here?

Comment: I set Cookie after authentication from S3, Every request that user makes from S3 includes this Cookie. Cloudfront forward everything to S3, The problem is that Cloudfront contains Cookie, but it doesn't send it to Lambda.

Comment: S3 is for static websites. Not sure how it is supposed to handle cookies? Do you have any aws doc references for such a functionality?

Comment: And it is still unclear how the services are supposed to interact - if cloudfront forwards the request to S3 it does not really make sense to forward cookies since s3 does not do anything with cookies, where does your lambda come into play, where does the second screenshot come from, what is it supposed to show, who sent that request?